# Synchronize different clients connected as the same user - Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets, server, synchronization, client

for a university project I developed a Client-Server application written in Java that allows multiple connections.
In short, the connections are "state-less"(?), each client has a token that identifies a specific user and performs operations (each operation opens the connection, writes the request, waits for the response and closes the connection).

Now, I have doubts with synchronization because it has a known problem: to try to synchronize operations on the same user I am using a **ConcurrentHashMap** that holds the **tuple[UUID, Object]**, the UUID is unique for each client that uses the same token user, the Object is the class on which I **synchronize** the methods that write and read on the disk.

The problem is that I add (if it doesn't exist) the tuple to the HashMap when the connection is opened and the token is valid, and I delete the tuple from the HashMap when the connection is closed.

As you can see, if two (or more) Clients want to do an operation on the same user at the same time, there is a risk that one will find the HashMap without his Tuple, but honestly (having never done it) I don't know how to solve the problem.

---

I tried to make a small outline of the possible flow of instructions on the server that would cause the error.
[image]

I hope I have been as clear as possible,
thanks for the help in advance.

---

I have tried to solve this problem with this class:

```java
/**
 * Singleton class
 */
public class SynchronizeManagerImpl<T> implements SynchronizeManager<T> {
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<T, SimpleLock> lockList;

    public SynchronizeManagerImpl() {
        lockList = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void createLock(T key) {
        SimpleLock lockClass = lockList.getOrDefault(key, new SimpleLock());
        lockClass.occurrences.incrementAndGet();
        lockList.putIfAbsent(key, lockClass);
    }

    @Override
    public Lock getWriteLock(T key) {
        SimpleLock lockClass = lockList.get(key);
        return lockClass.writeLock();
    }

    @Override
    public Lock getReadLock(T key) {
        SimpleLock lockClass = lockList.get(key);
        return lockClass.readLock();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteLock(T key) {
        SimpleLock lockClass = lockList.get(key);
        Lock writeLock = lockClass.writeLock();

        try {
            writeLock.lock();
            if (lockClass.occurrences.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
                lockList.remove(key);
            }
        } finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Lock class
     */
    private static final class SimpleLock extends ReentrantReadWriteLock {
        // Atomic and Volatile
        private final AtomicInteger occurrences = new AtomicInteger();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this needs code and maybe some diagrams, I'm not sure what you are describing.  Synchronization doesn't exist just for the sake of synchronizing, you need a reason.  Please tell us what the goal is.  Are the read-write sequences atomic?  Why?  Please describe in detail.  Likewise describe in detail other operations which do not need to be atomic and why.  Otherwise I think we have no hope of offering any help.

Comment: I tried to create a schema

Comment: Maybe you need to synchronize map accessing and your logic together?

Comment: So, you seem to be saying that you don't want one client (request) to read while another is writing.  The thing with these sorts of locks is that multiple reads is usually OK (is it in your case?).  For that, use a [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).

Comment: Your problem is far bigger than this one issue. In general you need to look into idempotent transactions.